# Is rsync strong enough for copying lots of files?

Tags: rsync

I'm new to rsync.

Lots of people said rsync is excellent in everything

how about copying lots of files in more than 10 GB, lots of directory at once?

Is rsync strong enough for this?

Comment: This question may have some good context for you: http://serverfault.com/questions/18125/how-to-copy-a-large-number-of-files-quickly-between-two-servers

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I use rsync to backup about 90GB of data over ADSL connections and it's always rock solid.  If you are transferring big files you might want to use the "--partial" flag so that way partially copied files are resumed rather than deleted and started again if the connection is interrupted.

Comment: I've also just used rsync to sync >2TB of data from various servers to a backup device, and it's also coped fine with that.  Some of the folders took absolutely ages because they contained lots and lots of small files, but it got there in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Rsync is prefectly capable of this. It will also help you if you need to run the transfer again, or abort it and resume later, as it will not recopy what is already there.

If you have reliable modification timestamps on your data, you may want to disable checksumming to speed up the process.

Comment: mostly right - but disabling checksumming is not a good idea - rsync will do block level operations on large files - if an operation fails to complete, the timestamp will be updated but the files won't be in sync

Answer (score 1):

Yes, rsync is absolutely capable of multi-gigabyte sustained transfers, as well as large lists of files.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, allways try to compress your information first. 
For large files, Rsync is able to resume transfers by using ‑‑partial and ‑‑inplace.
Take a look on this useful y detailed explanation: [Backup and transfer your data using rsync](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Backup_and_transfer_your_data_using_rsync)