# Running multiple scp threads simultaneously

Tags: linux, centos, scp, multi-threading

### Running multiple scp threads simultaneously:

### Background:

I'm often finding myself mirroring a set of server files a lot, and included in these server files are **thousands** of little 1kb-3kb files. All the servers are connected to 1Gbps ports, generally spread out in a variety of data-centers.

### Problem:

SCP transfers these little files, ONE by ONE, and it takes ages, and I feel like I'm wasting the beautiful network resources I have.

### Solution?:

I had an idea; Creating a script, which divides the files up into equal amounts, and starts up 5-6 scp threads, which theoretically would then get done 5-6 times faster, no? But I don't have any linux scripting experience!

### Question(s):

- Is there a better solution to the mentioned problem?
- Is there something like this that exists already?
- If not, is there someone who would give me a start, or help me out?
- If not to 2, or 3, where would be a good place to start looking to learn linux scripting? Like bash, or other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a large number of files quickly between two servers](http://serverfault.com/questions/18125/how-to-copy-a-large-number-of-files-quickly-between-two-servers)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would do it like this:
`tar -cf - /manyfiles | ssh dest.server 'tar -xf - -C /manyfiles'`

Depending on the files you are transferring it can make sense to enable compression in the `tar` commands:
`tar -czf - /manyfiles | ssh dest.server 'tar -xzf - -C /manyfiles'`

It may also make sense that you choose a CPU friendlier cipher for the `ssh` command (like arcfour):
`tar -cf - /manyfiles | ssh -c arcfour dest.server 'tar -xf - -C /manyfiles'`

Or combine both of them, but it really depends on what your bottleneck is.
Obviously `rsync` will be a lot faster if you are doing incremental syncs.

Answer (score 11):

Use `rsync` instead of `scp`. You can use `rsync` over `ssh` as easily as `scp`, and it supports "pipelining of file transfers to minimize latency costs".

One tip: If the data is compressible, enable compression. If it's not, disable it.

Comment: I just did one transfer last night with scp and am doing another similar transfer with rsync -- it *seems* a lot faster. However, it still seems to be transferring one file at a time — any idea how to make this do multiple threads (Beyond --include'ing and --exclude'ing a bunch of directories via script; see: http://sun3.org/archives/280)

Comment: There's no point transferring multiple files at the same time given the limited bandwidth. I believe you won't consider this command when the bandwidth is abundant. Eliminating the latency cost already helped a lot when you are coping a lot of small files. Even if you can copy multiple files at the same time, the limited bandwidth won't speed up your file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to suggest GNO [Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (which still requires some scripting work on your part), but then I found pscp (which is part of [pssh](http://www.theether.org/pssh/docs/0.2.3/pssh-HOWTO.html)). That may just fit your need.

Comment: It seems `pssh` operates concurrently to multiple machines. I don't think it implements file-level parallelism.

Comment: I probably should be specific - I meant pscp.

Answer (score 1):

Not scp directly, but an option for mutli threaded transfer (even on single files) is bbcp - https://www2.cisl.ucar.edu/resources/storage-and-file-systems/bbcp.

use the -s option for the number of threads you want transferring data.  Great for high bandwidth but laggy connections, as lag limits the TCP window size per thread.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly unrelated, but if you want something more real time you could try [GlusterFS](http://gluster.org). Works well, but requires some tuning if you're wanting to efficiently read small files.