# what is the fastest and most reliable way of transferring a lot of files?

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I'm trying to transfer about 100k files totaling 90gb. Right now I'm using rsync daemon but its slow 3.4mb/s and I need to do this a number of times. I'm wondering what options do I have that would max out a 100mbit connection over the internet and be very reliable.

Comment: You're getting nearly a third of your connection - that's respectable, but not great.  How far away as the electron flies are the files being transferred?

Comment: 50ms latency between the two servers.

Comment: I saw an alot of files once http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: If you are using rsync daemon, there is no ssh involved, right? Then the explanation is probably the infrastructure in between the hosts. You could try netperf or iperf or flowgrind to test the speed between the hosts. If this test gives you a higher transfer rate, then you should look at how rsync is making things slow: read i/o on server slow, write i/o on client, many small files, filesystem etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a large number of files quickly between two servers](http://serverfault.com/questions/18125/how-to-copy-a-large-number-of-files-quickly-between-two-servers)

Answer (score 11):

Have you considered [Sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)? With large data sets overnight shipping is often going to be faster and cheaper than transferring via the Internet.

Comment: "Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of tapes hurtling down the highway." - AST

Comment: well, given the affordability of gigabit LAN hardware, if its a LAN transfer, the time spent writing via eSATA to a single spindle is not all that attractive.

Answer (score 11):

### How? Or TL;DR

The fastest method I've found is a combination of `tar`, `mbuffer` and `ssh`.

E.g.:

```
tar zcf - bigfile.m4p | mbuffer -s 1K -m 512 | ssh otherhost "tar zxf -"
```

Using this I've achieved sustained local network transfers over 950 Mb/s on 1Gb links. Replace the paths in each tar command to be appropriate for what you're transferring.

### Why? mbuffer!

The biggest bottleneck in transferring large files over a network is, by far, disk I/O. The answer to that is `mbuffer` or `buffer`. They are largely similar but `mbuffer` has some advantages. The default buffer size is 2MB for `mbuffer` and 1MB for `buffer`. Larger buffers are more likely to never be empty. Choosing a block size which is the lowest common multiple of the native block size on both the target and destination filesystem will give the best performance.

**Buffering is the thing that makes *all* the difference!** Use it if you have it! If you don't have it, get it! Using `(m}?buffer` plus anything is better than anything by itself. it is almost literally a panacea for slow network file transfers.

If you're transferring multiple files use `tar` to "lump" them together into a single data stream. If it's a single file you can use `cat` or I/O redirection. The overhead of `tar` vs. `cat` is statistically insignificant so I always use `tar` (or `zfs -send` where I can) unless it's already a *tarball*. Neither of these is guaranteed to give you metadata (and in particular `cat` will not). If you want metadata, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Finally, using `ssh` for a transport mechanism is both secure and carries very little overhead. Again, the overhead of `ssh` vs. `nc` is statistically insignificant.

Comment: There's encryption overhead in using SSH as a transport sometimes. See: [**Copying files between linux machines with strong authentication without encryption**](http://serverfault.com/questions/452978/copying-files-between-linux-machines-with-strong-authentication-without-encrypti)

Comment: You can use faster encryption mechanisms if you need to. But you don't necessarily need to pipe this thru ssh. I prefer to set the -O and -I ports on mbuffer on both sides. Even tho this is now two commands, you skip the encryption and maximize network bandwidth by buffering both ends. I'm sending a tar stream at 720+Mbps on my local LAN with the equivalent of `tar -cf - .|mbuffer -m128k -s 256M -I 9090 & mbuffer -m128k -s 256M -O host:9090 | tar -xf -`

Comment: @memnoch_proxy: That's a good suggestion (which I up voted) but in this day and age where the NSA is even tapping private data lines between data centers (e.g., Google and Yahoo) using encryption, IMO, is always a good habit to make. Using `ssh` makes that simple. Using `stunnel`, `socat` or `openssl` works too, but they're more complex to set up for simple transfers.

Comment: @bahamat thank you for making me look at the question again. My suggestion only seems appropriate if the transfer can occur over a VPN then. For an Internet transfer, I would certainly use ssh as well.

Answer (score 8):

You mention "rsync," so I assume you are using Linux:

Why don't you create a tar or tar.gz file?  Network transfer time of one big file is faster than many small ones.  You could even compress it if you wish...

**Tar with no compression:**

On the source server:

```
tar -cf file.tar /path/to/files/
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
cd /path/to/files/
tar -xf /path/to/file.tar
```

**Tar with compression:**

On the source server:

```
tar -czf file.tar.gz /path/to/files/
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
cd /path/to/files/
tar -xzf /path/to/file.tar.gz
```

**You would simply use rsync to do the actual transfer of the (tar|tar.gz) files.**

Comment: only if there were available place for storing archive..

Answer (score 5):

You could try the `tar` and `ssh` trick described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/):

```
tar cvzf - /wwwdata | ssh root@192.168.1.201 "dd of=/backup/wwwdata.tar.gz"
```

this *should* be rewritable to the [following](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/03-09-2008/using-tar-and-ssh-improve-scp-speeds):

```
tar cvzf - /wwwdata | ssh root@192.168.1.201 "tar xvf -"
```

You'd lose the `--partial` features of `rsync` in the process, though. If the files don't change very frequently, living with a slow initial `rsync` could be highly worth-while as it will go *much* faster in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use various compression options of rsync.

```
-z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
     --compress-level=NUM    explicitly set compression level
     --skip-compress=LIST    skip compressing files with suffix in LIST
```

compression ratio for binary files is very low, so you can skip those files using --skip-compress e.g. iso, already archived and compressed tarballs etc.

Answer (score 0):

My best solution after a fair it of testing, is using rsync (tell me what files are different between 2 directories) to tar to zstd(compress with option level 2 works for me)  to mbuffer (to max out the network on my 1gb lan). And then reverse that on the receiving side.
On receiving side:
mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G -I8080 | tar -vx -C /zos25/z --use-compress-program=zstdmt
On sending side: (run cmd from /zos25/z)
rsync --info=name --out-format="%n" -ainAXEtp /zos25/z/ root@ipaddress:/zos25/z | tar -I 'zstdmt -2' -cvf - -T - | mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G -O ipaddress:8080

I ran ssh-keygen on both sides and copied keys so the ssh didn't ask for a password.

I have 4 way laptops at either end so CPU is not an issue, the network is the bottleneck, i get 70mb/s with data that's compressed about 80%. So its pretty efficient. I would recommend you play with 'zstdmt -2' value to see if greater or lesser compression effects thruput. A faster network could cope with lesser compression (zstdmt -1).

Answer (score -5):

I'm a big fan of SFTP. I use SFTP to transfer media from my main computer to my server. I get good speeds, over LAN.

SFTP is reliable, I'd give that a shot, as it's easy to set up, and it could be faster in some cases.

Comment: FTP needs to die. It's unencrypted, it does not handle interruption well, and there are at least half a dozen viable alternatives for it that don't completely suck.

Comment: Ever hear of SFTP?

Comment: Yes, have you? It is in no way related to the FTP protocol in anything except name and the fact that it moves files around.

Comment: FTP is also notoriously unreliable when traversing firewalls (it dates from a time before firewalls when having your client open a random port to accept back-connections was cool, and the hackery of Passive & Extended Passive FTP to work around that limitation is just that: Hackery)